# Thread scoped Spring Bean - is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a class which extends Thread. Each thread connects to own HTTP server.

How to configure Spring Bean and to pass custom domain for each thread?

As far as I know Spring supports such scopes: singleton, prototype, session, request.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a list of threads based on the properties. something like this:

The thread class.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

    private String domain; 

    public MyThread(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(domain);
    }

}
```

The property file:

```
t1.domain=www.domain1.com
t2.domain=www.domain2.com
```

The config class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:test.properties", name="testProperties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public List<MyThread> myThreads(){
        List<MyThread> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Iterator it = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource propertySource = (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource) it.next();

            if ("testProperties".equals(propertySource.getName())) {
                for(String propertyName : ((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getPropertyNames()){
                    list.add(new MyThread(propertySource.getProperty(propertyName).toString()));
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The class that uses the threads:

```
List<MyThread> ll = (List<MyThread>)context.getBean("myThreads");
        for(MyThread t : ll){
            Thread th = new Thread(t);
            th.start();
        }
```